# Swift For Loop Value of type 'AnyObject?' has no member 'Generator'

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I am trying to do this but it's says

> Value of type 'AnyObject?' has no member 'Generator'

So this is my code.

```
let dataDictionary:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                var customerArray = dataDictionary.valueForKey("kart")
                for js: NSDictionary in customerArray {
                    let nameArray: NSArray = js.valueForKey("name")
                }
```

What I am doing wrong.I didn't figure out.Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `customerArray` is an Optional, it has the type `AnyObject?` (this is because `.valueForKey` returns an Optional). You can't loop over an Optional. Solution is to cast the result as an array while safe unwrapping:

```
if let customerArray = dataDictionary.valueForKey("kart") as? NSArray {
    for js in customerArray {
        let nameArray = js.valueForKey("name")
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happend because `valueForKey` method returns `Optional` value of `AnyObject` type (`AnyObject?`). Indeed, `AnyObject` has no `Generator` member, and can't be used in `for..in` loop (as well as an `Optional` value). So, you should unwrap optional value and cast it to expected type, like this:

```
let dataDictionary:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
var customerArray = dataDictionary.valueForKey("kart")! as! [NSDictionary]
for js: NSDictionary in customerArray {
    let nameArray = js.valueForKey("name") as! NSArray
}
```