# Google Drive for iOS with cocoa pod leads to GTLQueryDrive errors

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, cocoapods

Using iOS-9.2.1, Xcode-7.2.1:

Still trying to follow the the '**Google-Drive API for iOS in Swift**' example (as described here: [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift)), I decided **not** to go with the framework - but with a cocoa-pod solution.

Here is my PodFile that worked:

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def shared_pods
    pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive', '~> 1.0'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Also, I needed to add the "MyApp-Bridging-Header.h" File as follows:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "GTLDrive.h"
```

After that, everything worked on my iPhone for exactly 1-Time !!
I was able to log into my google account that I created before following step-nr 1 in the mentioned [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift).

But after that, no further run was possible any more (neither on the simulator) !!
No code changed !!!

The following error suddenly occurred inside ViewController.swift :

[image]

Or the same as code here...

```
// When the view appears, ensure that the Drive API service is authorized
// and perform API calls
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
        canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
            fetchFiles()
    } else {
        presentViewController(
            createAuthController(),
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}

// Construct a query to get names and IDs of 10 files using the Google Drive API
func fetchFiles() {
    output.text = "Getting files..."
    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
    query.pageSize = 10
    query.fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
    )
}

// Parse results and display
func displayResultWithTicket(ticket : GTLServiceTicket,
    finishedWithObject response : GTLDriveFileList,
    error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var filesString = ""

        if let files = response.files() where !files.isEmpty {
            filesString += "Files:\n"
            for file in files as! [GTLDriveFile] {
                filesString += "\(file.name) (\(file.identifier))\n"
            }
        } else {
            filesString = "No files found."
        }

        output.text = filesString
}
```

What went wrong ?? Why are these 4 errors suddenly happening and just a moment ago everything was fine ??? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `valueForKey` method returns `Optional` value of `AnyObject` type. You can't loop over an Optional. You should unwrap optional value and cast it to expected type. Example can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567231/swift-for-loop-value-of-type-anyobject-has-no-member-generator).Also, `let` being a protocol, Swift doesn't know what kind of object your function's incoming `let` is. You can't assign to a property of a constant struct as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241411/cannot-assign-to-property-in-protocol-swift-compiler-error).

Comment: Thank you abielita ! I just wonder why Google presents the above code as their preferred Swift solution --> see [Drive API for iOS - Swift... see Step 4 and 5 (code in ViewController example)](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift). Any idea on how the correct code looks like ??